# Посчитать сумму заказов по дате создания

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в таблице БД MySQL записаны заказы. Нужно получить количество заказов по дням за 7 дней, и посчитать их сумму. Делаю так, сначала получаю дату -7 дней.

```
$ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days'));
```

А потом делаю запрос:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) AS counter, DATE_FORMAT(`date_created`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS created_at FROM `table_orders` WHERE `date_created` > '{$ago}' GROUP BY `created_at`
```

Так я получаю количество заказов по дням. Вопрос - как посчитать еще и сумму заказов на каждую дату? Стоимость каждого заказа хранится в поле totalsum в той же таблице.

Answer (score 0):

Туплю.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) AS counter, SUM(totalsum) AS tsum, DATE_FORMAT(`date_created`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS created_at FROM `table_orders` WHERE `date_created` > '{$ago}' GROUP BY `created_at`
```